# Correlation matrix ignoring NaN

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am using matlab and I have a (60x882) matrix and I need to compute pairwise correlations between columns. However I want to ignore all the columns which have a NaN or more (i.e. the result for any pair of columns in which at least one entry is NaN should be NaN).

Here's my code so far:

```
for i=1:size(auxret,2)
    for j=1:size(auxret,2)
        rho(i,j)=corr(auxret(:,i),auxret(:,j));
        end
    end
end
```

But this is extremely innefficient. I considered using the function:

corr(auxret, 'rows','pairwise');
But it didn't produce the same result (it ignores NaNs but still computes the correlation - so unless all entries of a column except one are NaN it will still give an output).

Any suggestions on how to improve efficiency?

Comment: Just curious, doesn't my answer work? If not, what did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same output as your code using `corr(auxret, 'rows','pairwise')`, the following does the job

```
auxret(:,any(isnan(auxret))) = NaN;
r = corr(auxret, 'rows','pairwise');
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an efficient approach, specially when dealing with input data involving `NaNs` -

```
%// Get mask of invalid columns and thus extract columns without any NaN
mask = any(isnan(auxret),1);
A = auxret(:,~mask);

%// Use correlation formula to get correlation outputs for valid columns
n = size(A,1);
sum_cols = sum(A,1);
sumsq_sqcolsum = n*sum(A.^2,1) - sum_cols.^2;

val1 = n.*(A.'*A) - bsxfun(@times,sum_cols.',sum_cols);      %//'
val2 = sqrt(bsxfun(@times,sumsq_sqcolsum.',sumsq_sqcolsum)); %//'
valid_outvals = val1./val2;

%// Setup output array and store the valid outputs in it
ncols = size(auxret,2);
valid_idx = find(~mask);
out = nan(ncols);
out(valid_idx,valid_idx) = valid_outvals;
```

Basically, as the pre-processing step, it altogether removes all columns having one or more `NaNs` and calculates the correlation outputs. Then we initialize an output array of `NaNs` with *appropriate size* and puts back the valid outputs into it at *appropriate places*.

---

### Benchmarking

It seems the results are valid whether you stay with your loopy approach or go with the optional `corr(auxret, 'rows','pairwise')`. But, there is a big catch here: Even a single `NaN`
in any of the columns slows down the performance quite a bit and this performance drop is huge with the original loopy approach and still big with the `rows + pairwise` option as we will
find out in the benchmarking results next up.

**Benchmarking code**

```
nrows = 60;
ncols = 882;
percent_nans = 1; %// decides the percentage of NaNs in input

auxret = rand(nrows,ncols);
auxret(randperm(numel(auxret),round((percent_nans/100)*numel(auxret))))=nan;

disp('------------------------------- With Proposed Approach')
tic
%// Solution code from earlier
toc

disp('------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach')
tic
auxret(:,any(isnan(auxret))) = NaN;
out1 = corr(auxret, 'rows','pairwise');
toc

disp('------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach')
tic
out2 = zeros(size(auxret,2));
for i=1:size(auxret,2)
    for j=1:size(auxret,2)
        out2(i,j)=corr(auxret(:,i),auxret(:,j));
    end
end
toc
```

So, there are few cases possible based on the input datasizes and percentage of `NaNs` and correspondingly we have the runtime results -

**Case 1: Input is `6 x 88` and Percentage of NaNs is `10`**

```
------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.006371 seconds.
------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach
Elapsed time is 0.052563 seconds.
------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach
Elapsed time is 0.875620 seconds.
```

**Case 2: Input is `6 x 88` and Percentage of NaNs is `1`**

```
------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.006303 seconds.
------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach
Elapsed time is 0.049194 seconds.
------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach
Elapsed time is 0.871369 seconds.
```

**Case 3: Input is `6 x 88` and Percentage of NaNs is `0.001`**

```
------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.006738 seconds.
------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach
Elapsed time is 0.025754 seconds.
------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach
Elapsed time is 0.867647 seconds.
```

**Case 4: Input is `60 x 882` and Percentage of NaNs is `10`**

```
------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.007766 seconds.
------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach
Elapsed time is 2.479645 seconds.
------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach
...... Taken Too long ...
```

**Case 5: Input is `60 x 882` and Percentage of NaNs is `1`**

```
------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.014144 seconds.
------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach
Elapsed time is 2.324878 seconds.
------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach
...... Taken Too long ...
```

**Case 6: Input is `60 x 882` and Percentage of NaNs is `0.001`**

```
------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.020410 seconds.
------------------------------- With ROWS + PAIRWISE Approach
Elapsed time is 1.830632 seconds.
------------------------------- With Original Loopy Approach
...... Taken Too long ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the default behavior of `corr` without any special options. For example,

```
auxret =  [8     2     3
           3     5     NaN
           7    10     3
           7     4     6
           2     6     7];

rho = corr(auxret)
```

results in

```
rho =

    1.0000   -0.1497       NaN
   -0.1497    1.0000       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN
```